# Olá, eu sou novo em Python, e estou tendo problema com um SyntaxError em um else

Tags: python, syntax-error, else

[image]

Ele aparenta estar escrito de maneira correta, mas mesmo assim esta dando erro. Não importa o que eu faça o erro continua, eu já tentei trocar por um elif, por um if, mas nada da certo. Sempre dá um SyntaxError.

Comment: Faltou um ) na linha acima do else.

Comment: Olá, falta fechar o parentesis no 2o print.

Comment: Ops, nem percebi, acabei procurando o erro apenas no else e nem vi, obrigado

Comment: É lgo comum com erros de sintaxe - nem sempre onde o Python deixa de entender o que está acontecendo é a linha que está o problema. As vezes é algumas linhas antes. Nesse caso, como o pessoal comentou, faltou fechar o parênteses na linha acima do else.

Comment: E por favor coloque o código como texto. Colocá-lo como imagem não é o ideal, entenda os motivos [lendo o **FAQ**](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5485/112052).

Comment: Ok, apartir de agora eu ponho apenas em códigos.

Comment: A partir de agora não, comece com essa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@GabrielBellasco, o erro que consta no "else" na realidade é antes dele !
Faltou você fechar o parentêses do print. Você abriu, mas não fecho !

OBS:Ai vai uma dica.. sempre que acusar um SyntaxError, procure o erro. Quando encontrar o mesmo sublinhado como no exemplo do seu programa que é o "Else", sempre procure na linha superior pois o erro será da linha acima.
Quando estava aprendendo C, sempre tinha esses erros e tinha o mesmo problema que você !
Fica a dica para ajudar você a programar.